# Randomizing NGINX proxy_ssl_ciphers

Tags: nginx

Is is possible to somehow randomize the order of proxy_ssl_ciphers in NGINX?

I've even tried to set the proxy_ssl_ciphers with a value stored in variable, but in that case I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("$myCiphers") failed (SSL: error:140E6118:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_process_rulestr:invalid command)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: I doubt that, since I think this string is directly passed to the TLS library as configuration. What is your motivation for this?